# How to combine two toggle functions?

Tags: jquery

Im looking for a solution to connect these functions.
If someone opens the shoppingBag and the customerAccount is opened, the customerAccount should hide.

thanks for any help,

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    function change() {
        $('#shoppingBag').css('display', 'block');
    }

    function reset() {
        $('#shoppingBag').css('display', 'none');
    }

    $('.icon-cart').toggle(change, reset);


});

$(document).ready(function () {

    function change() {
        $('.customerAccount').css('display', 'block');
    }

    function reset() {
        $('.customerAccount').css('display', 'none');
    }

    $('.icon-online, .icon-offline').toggle(change, reset);


});  
</script>
```

Comment: You duplicated everything. You declared twice each function, this just can't work. The second declaration overrides the first one.

Comment: on which event you are toggling these two?

Comment: post your html code.

Comment: FYI: toggling events using .toggle has been deprecated in version 1.8 and removed in version 1.9. http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write `document.ready` multiple times, single will do. Put all your script inside `document.ready`.

You can put click even for your cart and offline / online icon, to toggle between shopping cart and customer.

**NOTE** - instead of changing display css to show / hide, you can use `show()` / `hide()` functions provided by jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.icon-cart').click(function(){
      $('.customerAccount').hide();
      $('#shoppingBag').toggle();
    });

    $('.icon-online, .icon-offline').click(function(){
      $('.customerAccount').toggle();
      $('#shoppingBag').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like :

```
var $shoppingBag = $('#shoppingBag'), // Caching for performance
    $customerAccount = $('.customerAccount'),
    onShow = 1;


$(document).ready(function () { // Only one!! Why two?

    function showOnly1() { // Unique function !!
        $shoppingBag.show();
        $customerAccount.hide();
        onShow = 1;
    }

    function showOnly2() { // Unique function !!
        $shoppingBag.hide();
        $customerAccount.show();
        onShow = 2;
    }

    $('#someButton').click(function(){
       if(onShow==1){
           showOnly2();
       } else {
           showOnly1();
       }
    });


});
```

Comment: And downvoted without reason again, I'm seriously pissed off with that